# how to repeat code for certain counts?

Tags: android, repeat

How do I repeat the Toast for a certain amount of times and not just have it loop like it does now while considering the the timer delay?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button btn;
    EditText edit;
    TextView view;
    Timer myTimer = new Timer();
    MyTimerTask myTimerTask= new MyTimerTask();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.bu);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {               
                edit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed1);
                view=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.te);

                int aa = Integer.valueOf(edit.getText().toString());

                view.setText(edit.getText().toString());
                myTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(myTimerTask, aa, aa);
            }
        });
    }

    private class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run()
                    //code to do
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Toast test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //how to repeat this toast for certain counts not just looping like now
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could increment a counter in each execution of `MyTimerTask.run()`. Then when this counter equals the amount of times you want it to show the Toast notification, you can cancel the `TimerTask` with `myTimer.cancel();`.

Comment: The amount of times i want the Toast to be shown will be entered by the user. so what I am going to need is int to string it.excuse my English.

Comment: In that case, simply store the value that was entered in a class field and compare the class field with the counter.

Comment: Dont you think if i use `CountDownTimer` it ll be easier and more simple?the problem still how to repeat it to me . if you dont mind can you write a code to repeat  `CountDownTimer`?

Comment: The `CountDownTimer` is only the best tool for this if you're interested in counting down to a certain point in time rather than doing something `x` times. Either way, a simple example would be as such: http://pastebin.com/dVm7VDP6

Comment: thank you you were very helpful. actually its not Toast what i want to repeat, its more complicated code .thanks for help